# Giving Segmentation fault and idk where

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a program in C where the user inputs something and if one of the words is within an array (in this case is **biblio**) but when i'm going to test it it gives me **Segmentation Fault (core dumped)**.
I know that this error appears when the program tries to access to a memory field that it can't, but i can't find where it does that and how to fix it. Can someone help me ?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

int within(char* str, char * biblio[], int size)
{
    char * aux;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        aux = biblio[i];
        if(strcmp(str, aux) == 0 )
            return 1; //return 1 --> the word exists in biblio array
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int iterations = 5;
    int size = 50, count = 0;
    char * biblio[] = {"mostarda", "ketchup", "maionese"};
    char * input[size];
    char * str = NULL;
    int ret;
    while(iterations > 0)
    {
        do{
            printf("Enter a value: ");
            scanf("%s", str);
            ret = within(str, biblio, sizeof (biblio));
            if(ret == 1)
            {
                memset(input, 0, sizeof(input)); //clear biblio
                break;
            }
            input[count] = str;
            count++;
        }while( (strcmp(str, "EOF")) == 0);

        printf("%s", input);
        iterations--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Many thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, compile for debug with `gcc -g` and then run the binary under `gdb`. When it coredumps, give gdb the `where` command to see the full call stack, showing the line number in your program where it failed.

Here, for example, is my gdb session figuring out the cause. I run the program in gdb with `gdb ./a.out` then enter a test value. When it crashes, it shows the error is in an (assembly) implementation of `strcmp` (I don't have that library source file, hence the "No such file or directory".  I go `up 1` to move the view up one level in the stack (into your `within` function) and there I print the values of the two arguments to `strcmp`.  One of them is patently not what it should be.

```
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/p/a.out 
Enter a value: 10

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S:31
31  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) up 1
#1  0x00005555555547f4 in within (str=0x0, biblio=0x7fffffffe450, size=24) at foo.c:11
11          if(strcmp(str, aux) == 0 )
(gdb) print (str)
$1 = 0x0
(gdb) print (aux)
$2 = 0x555555554a44 "mostarda"
```

Comment: The problem was in fact the strcmp... I'm just going to do it by hand.. Many thanks man :D

Answer (score 1):

Look at these lines:

```
char * str = NULL;                     // str is a pointer equal NULL
int ret;
while(iterations > 0)
{
    do{
        printf("Enter a value: ");
        scanf("%s", str);              // Here you read data into str which is NULL
                                       // That will cause a program crash
```

Make sure that `str` points to some allocated memory before putting data into it.

Maybe you could do:

```
    do{
        str = malloc(MAX_SIZE_OF_INPUT);  // Allocate memory for the string
        if (str == NULL)
        {
            // Out of memory
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Enter a value: ");
```

And another detail:

```
}while( (strcmp(str, "EOF")) == 0);
```

I guess you want

```
}while( (strcmp(str, "EOF")) != 0);
```

BTW: Never do:

```
        scanf("%s", str);
```

as that can overflow any buffer that `str` points to. Always put a limit to the number of characters to read. Like

```
        scanf("%100s", str);  // Maximum is 100
```

Comment: Ok, i'm going to try that. i thought that scanf would work like a streamer.get() in java. Maybe that's the cause of all of this

Comment: @LuisVaz I don't know much about java.... but in C you must allocate memory and have the pointer point to that memory before reading data.

Comment: It still gives me **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

Comment: You have a similar problem here: `memset(input, 0, sizeof(input)); //clear biblio` There's no memory assigned to `input` som `memset` will crash

Comment: Found the problem !! it was the strcmp, going to change it. But i'll have my attention up there. thanks :D